# ansible print debug msg variable

Tags: deployment, ansible

I try to print the previously registered `mosh_version` variable using the ansible `debug msg` command like this:

```
- name: Print mosh version
  debug: msg="Mosh Version: {{ mosh_version.stdout }}"
```

It doesn't work and prints the following error:

```
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 55, column 27

- name: Print mosh version
  debug: msg="Mosh Version: {{ mosh_version.stdout }}"
                          ^
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

I tried

```
- name: Print mosh version
  debug: msg=Mosh Version: "{{ mosh_version.stdout }}"
```

but this will just print "Mosh".

What's the best way to get this running?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
- name: Print mosh version
  debug: "msg=Mosh Version: '{{ mosh_version.stdout }}'"
```

More info in http://docs.ansible.com/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas

Edited:
Something like this works perfect for me:

```
- name: Check Ansible version
  command: ansible --version
  register: ansibleVersion

- name: Print version
  debug:
    msg: "Ansible Version: {{ ansibleVersion.stdout }}"
```

http://pastie.org/private/cgeqjucn3l5kxhkkyhtpta

Comment: There are no more syntax errors, but it doesn't work either: ```TASK: [ Print mosh version] **************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "Mosh"
}
```

Comment: Try first just print variable and see output without custom message, like this:


- name: Print mosh version
  debug: var=mosh_version.stdout_lines

Comment: `ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "var": {
        "mosh_version.stdout_lines": [
            "mosh 1.2.4a [build mosh-1.2.4-57-g9eeb2fb]"
        ]
    }
}
` this works, I'd really prefer the custom message though ;-)

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Please note: debug: "msg=Mosh Version: '{{ mosh_version.stdout }}'" will display only "Mosh". The msg="..." must be in quotes, instead of the whole message. But answer from @xddsg works better, as it is more detailed var dump.

Answer (score 12):

Simplest answer

```
- debug: var=mosh_version.stdout
```

Answer (score 3):

I have displayed variable and message in the same debug play.

**Ansible Task**

```
- name: Report the /boot/initramfs file status for latest installed kernel
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_hostname }} =  {{INITRAMFS_LAST_KERNEL.stdout}}"
```

**Output**

```
TASK [os-upgrade.linux : Report the /boot/initramfs file status for latest installed kernel] *******************************************
ok: [ANSIBLENODE] => {
    "msg": "ANSIBLENODE =  /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64.img"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the colon

```
debug: msg="Mosh Version {{ mosh_version.stdout }}"
```

Comment: Honestly, this is not a full solution but still it worked and solved the next issue I had. Can't use the other syntax because I use it with `when` so removing the colon actually is the simplest way to solve this. so I upvote ;)

Answer (score 2):

Anytime I have problems with special characters in Ansible strings/cmds I do this:

1. Wrap with single quotes
2. Wrap with double curly brackets

So your standard colon becomes `{{':'}}`

And your task becomes:

```
- debug: msg="Ansible Version{{':'}} {{ ansibleVersion.stdout }}"
```

Again this works for most special characters, even strings.  Consider the following:

```
docker ps --format '{{.Names}}'
```

In order to run this in Ansible, just apply the same logic, the following task executes as expected:

```
- name: Get the docker container names
  become: yes
  shell: "docker ps --format '{{'{{'}}.Names{{'}}'}}'"
  register: docker_containers
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this, notice the location of double quotes(") and single quotes(')

```
- name: Print mosh version
  debug: "msg='Mosh Version: {{ mosh_version.stdout }}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Print somevariable
  debug:
    var: somevariable
```